# Como puedo incrementar un valor por 0.5 por cada incremento de 1 de otro valor

Tags: javascript

Necesito restar 0.5 de un valor especifico, cada vez que otro valor sea incrementado por uno.

Esto es para mostrar la cantidad de dinero en la pantalla al jugador.

Por cada longitud total del dinero del jugador, si es mayor a 6, necesito que la ubicacion del dinero en la pantalla sea disminuida por 0.5 (mover las letras hacia la isquierda, para que no desaparescan de la pantalla).

Por ejemplo, si el dinero total es $100,000 (6 digitos), la posicion del dinero disminuya por 0.5.

Si el dinero es $1,000,000 (7 digitos), la posicion del dinero disminuya por 1.

O si son 8 digitos, la posicion disminuya por 1.5.

Encontre esta manera de hacerlo, pero es totalmente manual.

```js
// amount es la cantidad de dinero
// scaleX es la posicion horizontal del dinero
switch(amount.toString().length){
    case 6:
    scaleX -= 0.5;
    break;
    case 7:
    scaleX -= 1;
    break;
    case 8:
    scaleX -= 1.5;
    break;
    case 9:
    scaleX -= 2;
    break;
    case 10:
    scaleX -= 2.5;
    break;
}
```

Hay una manera de lograr esto de una manera automatica?

Intente con esto:

```js
var i;
var sum = 0.5;
for(i = 6; i == amount.toString().length; i++){
    if(i < 6){
        continue;
    }
    scaleX -+ sum;
    console.log('Sum: ' + sum);
    console.log('I: ' + i);
    sum+= 0.5;
}
```

Pero realmente no logro nada.

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Para esta respuesta tener en cuenta que estoy suponiendo que la variable **scaleX** contiene la cantidad de posiciones (en la unidad de medida que se maneje) a mover los números.

Partiendo de los supuestos:

- Se sabe la posición actual. Denominada **y**
- La cantidad de dígitos antes de mover es fija. La denominaremos cantidadMaximaDigitosFijos
- La distancia a mover es fijo. La denominaremos coeficientePosicionesMover.
- cantidadDigitos representa la cantidad actual de dígitos.

Cuando cantidadDigitos > cantidadMaximaDigitosFigos, se puede aplicar la formula:

> x = y - coficientePosicionesMover * (cantidadDigitos - cantidadMaximaDigitosFijos)

Ejemplo:

Si:

- y = 20
- CoeficientePosicionesMover = 0.5
- CantidadDigitos = 7
- CantidadMaximaDigitosFijos = 5

Entonces: x = 20 - 0.5 * (7 - 5) => x = 20 - 0.5 * 2 => x = 20 - 1 => x = 19

```
var cantidadMaximaDigitosFijos = 5;
var coeficientePosicionesMover = 0.5;
var cantidadDigitos = amount.toString().length;

if (cantidadDigitos > cantidadMaximaDigitosFijos) {
  //En el código y = x (scaleX)
  scaleX -= coeficientePosicionMover * (cantidadDigitos - cantidadMaximaDigitosFijos)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

he estado repasando tu codigo y he hecho algun cambio, prueba con este codigo:

```
var i;
var sum = -0.5;
for(i = 6; i <= amount.toString().length; i++){
    if(i < 6){
        continue;
    }
    scaleX -+ sum;
    console.log('Sum: ' + sum);
    console.log('I: ' + i);
    sum-= 0.5;
}
```

espero que resuelva tu problema